# How to log on to my wsj account from linux terminal (using curl, oauth2.0)

Tags: bash, curl, web-scraping

I'm a paid member of wsj and I want to log onto my wsj account from linux terminal so I can write codes to **scrape** some articles to for my NLP research. I won't release the data whatsoever.

My approach is based on a previous answer from [Scrape articles form wsj by requests, CURL and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965524/scrape-articles-form-wsj-by-requests-curl-and-beautifulsoup?newreg=99fe3b2929274940939e932c674f6ac6)
The main issue with the codes that work back then but do not work now is that apparently wsj has adopted a different OAuth 2.0 approach. First, connection I cannot obtain anymore by running login_url. I kinda feel this is the bottleneck. It is a mandatory field for next step.

Another thing I notice is state parameter is used. I don't know how to use this field. After running

```
curl -s 'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/authorize?scope=openid+idp_id+roles+email+given_name+family_name+djid+djUsername+djStatus+trackid+tags+prts&client_id=XXXXXXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.wsj.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=https://www.wsj.com&username=XXXXXX&password=XXXXXX'
```

It does return:
"Found. Redirecting to /login?state=XXXX...."
But not sure how to use the state parameter after this step.

Some references I used are:
https://developer.dowjones.com/site/global/develop/authentication/index.gsp#2-exchanging-the-authorization-code-for-authn-tokens-98
https://oauth.net/2/

```
username="user@gmail.com"
password="YourPassword"

login_url=$(curl -s -I "https://accounts.wsj.com/login")
connection=$(echo "$login_url" | grep -oP "Location:\s+.*connection=\K(\w+)")
client_id=$(echo "$login_url" | grep -oP "Location:\s+.*client_id=\K(\w+)")

#connection=$(echo "$login_url" | gawk 'match($0, /Location:\s+.*connection=(\w+)&/, data) {print data[1]}')
#client_id=$(echo "$login_url" | gawk 'match($0, /Location:\s+.*client_id=(\w+)&/, data) {print data[1]}')

rm -f cookies.txt

IFS='|' read -r wa wresult wctx < <(curl -s 'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/usernamepassword/login' \
      --data-urlencode "username=$username" \
      --data-urlencode "password=$password" \
      --data-urlencode "connection=$connection" \
      --data-urlencode "client_id=$client_id" \
      --data 'scope=openid+idp_id&tenant=sso&response_type=code&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.wsj.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin' | pup 'input json{}' | jq -r 'map(.value) | join("|")')

# replace double quote ""
wctx=$(echo "$wctx" | sed 's/&#34;/"/g')

code_url=$(curl -D - -s -c cookies.txt 'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login/callback' \
     --data-urlencode "wa=$wa" \
     --data-urlencode "wresult=$wresult" \
     --data-urlencode "wctx=$wctx" | grep -oP "Location:\s+\K(\S*)")

curl -s -c cookies.txt "$code_url"

# here call your URL loading cookies.txt
curl -s -b cookies.txt "https://www.wsj.com/articles/singapore-prime-minister-lee-rejects-claims-he-misused-state-powers-in-family-feud-1499094761?tesla=y"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more parameters needed for the `/usernamepassword/login` request. It needs the `state` and `nonce`. Also it seems the `connection` field is no longer present in Location header but hardcoded in a js file.

The credentials details are embedded in a Base64 encoded JSON inside a script tag under https://accounts.wsj.com/login

You can update the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script as the following. It uses [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) & [pup](/questions/tagged/pup):

```bash
#/bin/bash

username="your_email@gmail.com"
password="your_password"
base_url="https://accounts.wsj.com"

rm -f cookies.txt

login_page=$(curl -s -L -c cookies.txt "$base_url/login")
jspage=$(echo "$login_page" | pup 'script attr{src}' | grep "app-min")
connection=$(curl -s "$base_url$jspage" | sed -rn "s/.*connection:\s*\"(\w+)\".*/\1/p" | head -1)

crendentials=$(echo "$login_page" | \
       sed -rn "s/.*Base64\.decode\('(.*)'.*/\1/p" | \
       base64 -d | \
       jq -r '.internalOptions.state, .internalOptions.nonce, .clientID')

read state nonce clientID < <(echo $crendentials)

echo "state:      $state"
echo "nonce:      $nonce"
echo "client_id:  $clientID"
echo "connection: $connection"

login_result=$(curl -s  -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt 'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/usernamepassword/login' \
      --data-urlencode "username=$username" \
      --data-urlencode "password=$password" \
      --data-urlencode "connection=$connection" \
      --data-urlencode "client_id=$clientID" \
      --data-urlencode "state=$state" \
      --data-urlencode "nonce=$nonce" \
      --data-urlencode "scope=openid idp_id roles email given_name family_name djid djUsername djStatus trackid tags prts" \
      --data 'tenant=sso&response_type=code&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.wsj.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin' | \
      pup 'input json{}' | jq -r '.[] | .value')

read wa wresult wctx < <(echo $login_result)

wctx=$(echo "$wctx" | sed 's/&#34;/"/g') #replace double quote ""

echo "wa:      $wa"
echo "wresult: $wresult"
echo "wctx:    $wctx"

callback=$(curl -s -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -L 'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login/callback' \
     --data-urlencode "wa=$wa" \
     --data-urlencode "wresult=$wresult" \
     --data-urlencode "wctx=$wctx")

#try this one to get an article, your username should be embedded in the page as logged in user
#curl -s -b cookies.txt "https://www.wsj.com/articles/singapore-prime-minister-lee-rejects-claims-he-misused-state-powers-in-family-feud-1499094761?tesla=y"
```

But this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script is painful to maintain, I'd recommend to use a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script like this:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import base64
import json

username="your_email@gmail.com"
password="your_password"
base_url="https://accounts.wsj.com"

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get("{}/login".format(base_url))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
jscript = [ 
    t.get("src") 
    for t in soup.find_all("script") 
    if t.get("src") is not None and "app-min" in t.get("src")
][0]

credentials_search = re.search("Base64\.decode\('(.*)'", r.text, re.IGNORECASE)
base64_decoded = base64.b64decode(credentials_search.group(1))
credentials = json.loads(base64_decoded)

print("client_id : {}".format(credentials["clientID"]))
print("state     : {}".format(credentials["internalOptions"]["state"]))
print("nonce     : {}".format(credentials["internalOptions"]["nonce"]))
print("scope     : {}".format(credentials["internalOptions"]["scope"]))

r = session.get("{}{}".format(base_url, jscript))

connection_search = re.search('connection:\s*\"(\w+)\"', r.text, re.IGNORECASE)
connection = connection_search.group(1)

r = session.post(
    'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/usernamepassword/login',
    data = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "connection": connection,
        "client_id": credentials["clientID"],
        "state": credentials["internalOptions"]["state"],
        "nonce": credentials["internalOptions"]["nonce"],
        "scope": credentials["internalOptions"]["scope"],
        "tenant": "sso",
        "response_type": "code",
        "protocol": "oauth2",
        "redirect_uri": "https://accounts.wsj.com/auth/sso/login"
    })
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

login_result = dict([ 
    (t.get("name"), t.get("value")) 
    for t in soup.find_all('input') 
    if t.get("name") is not None
])

r = session.post(
    'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login/callback',
    data = login_result)

#check connected user
r = session.get("https://www.wsj.com/articles/singapore-prime-minister-lee-rejects-claims-he-misused-state-powers-in-family-feud-1499094761?tesla=y")
username_search = re.search('\"firstName\":\s*\"(\w+)\",', r.text, re.IGNORECASE)
print("connected user : " + username_search.group(1))
```

Comment: I don't know how much gratitude and admire I have for you, man. How on earth you know to look for connection parameter in js object. I was really close except the connection parameter but that part could literally take me another 10 years to figure it out. Python codes are too awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: You’re welcome. It happens that you need to look into html or js file to find embedded or hardcode value. you can accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: I already did. It seems stack overflow is not reflecting it. Thanks again for explaining the reasoning.

Comment: It seems 'https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/usernamepassword/login' this part of codes does not work now. Is there a way to know what fields they require now versus before? I checked that all the fields provided such as nonce, scope are still valid. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried to add ns and ui_locales but that does not seem to help :(